# How to make content to show on both www and non-www urls using traefik

Tags: traefik

Thank you for showing interest and I was in a hurry. Any help would be great.
At present users were not able to reach www.example.com but they can reach example.com.

Either one of them is fine:

1) Accepts all traffic from WWW and non-www urls and serve same content.

2) Redirect users from WWW to non-www url to display content.

Note: Let's Encrypt is used

My present config is

**traefik.toml**

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.dashboard]
    address = ":8080"
    [entryPoints.dashboard.auth]
      [entryPoints.dashboard.auth.basic]
        users = ["admin:key"]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      regex = "^https://www.(.*)"
      replacement = "https://$1"
      permanent=true
        entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]

[api]
entrypoint="dashboard"

[acme]
email = "mail@gmail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.example.com"
  sans = ["example.com"]
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.example1.com"
  sans = ["example1.com"]
[docker]
domain = "example.com"
watch = true
network = "proxy"`
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
 version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    restart: always
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $PWD/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - $PWD/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: trefik
    environment:
      DO_AUTH_TOKEN: TOKEN
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.example.com
      - traefik.port=8080
  example1:
    image: wordpress:4.7.5-apache
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: something
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=example1
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example1.com
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.port=80
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  example:
   image: tutum/apache-php
   restart: always
   labels:
     - traefik.backend=example
     - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com, www.example.com
     - traefik.docker.network=proxy
     - traefik.port=80
   networks:
     - internal
     - proxy
```

Edit #1:

```
Your config Redirects:

http://example.com => [no redirect]

https://www.example.com => [timeout]

http://www.example.com => [timeout]

http://example.com => [no redirect]

My Config Redirects:

http://example.com => https://example.com:443/

https://www.example.com => [timeout]

http://www.example.com => [timeout]

http://example.com => https://example.com:443/
```

Comment: You can redirect www to non-www, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162076/www-to-non-www-redirect-using-request-variables-with-traefik

Comment: I did checked it out previously but unable to achieve this so then i have posted a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You cannot use redirect `entrypoint` and `regex` at the same on the same entrypoint.

> Please note that `regex` and `replacement` do not have to be set in the redirect structure if an entrypoint is defined for the redirection (they will not be used in this case).
>
> https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/entrypoints/#redirect-http-to-https

2. The wildcard certficates cannot be obtain with the HTTP challenge: https://docs.traefik.io/v.7/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains
   You have to use the DNS challenge https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#dnschallenge (edited) 
   and before you ask: you cannot use both (HTTP challenge and DNS challenge) at the same time.

---

**Edit**

I will illustrate the redirections with 2 simple configurations (self-signed certificates instead of acme but it's the same thing).

Those 2 configurations works without any changes, you only need to do `docker-compose up`.

Note that redirection has no influence on the HTTP challenge (ACME).

### Strip www and HTTPS redirection

The goal:

```sh
$ curl --insecure -L http://www.whoami.docker.localhost
# http://www.whoami.docker.localhost -> https://whoami.docker.localhost

$ curl --insecure -L https://www.whoami.docker.localhost
# https://www.whoami.docker.localhost -> https://whoami.docker.localhost

$ curl --insecure -L http://whoami.docker.localhost
# http://whoami.docker.localhost -> https://whoami.docker.localhost

$ curl --insecure -L https://whoami.docker.localhost
# https://whoami.docker.localhost -> https://whoami.docker.localhost
```

#### I. Example without TOML: (`docker-compose.yml`)

```
version: "3"

services:
  reverseproxy:
    image: traefik:v1.7.8
    command:
      - --logLevel=INFO
      - --defaultentrypoints=http,https
      - --entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.Regex:^http://(?:www\.)?(.+) Redirect.Replacement:https://$$1 Redirect.Permanent:true
      - --entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS Redirect.Regex:^https://www\.(.+) Redirect.Replacement:https://$$1 Redirect.Permanent:true
      - --docker
      - --docker.domain=docker.localhost
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

#### II. Example with TOML: (`docker-compose.yml` + `traefik.toml`)

```
version: "3"

services:
  reverseproxy:
    image: traefik:v1.7.8
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      regex = "^http://(?:www\.)?(.+)"
      replacement = "https://$1"
      permanent = true
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.redirect]
      regex = "^https://www\\.(.+)"
      replacement = "https://$1"
      permanent = true
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[api]

[docker]
domain = "docker.localhost"
```

Comment: Hi, I have removed the regex in http entrypoint and added it in the https entrypoint but still no luck. WWW urls are not reachable. If it's possible can you please edit my .toml code. Thank you.

Comment: With this config i was not able to access both www and non-www urls. Previously i was able to access through non-www urls. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my question and shown you some info at the bottom about the redirects of the urls. Those are grabbed through a python script which i wrote.

Comment: could you replace `image: traefik` by `image: traefik:v1.7.8`